# Using any generic class on an interface and avoid many types

Tags: c#, generics

I have this generic interface:

```
public interface IBaseInterface<T, TU> 
  where T: InterfaceT
  where TU: InterfaceTU
{
    T SomeClassT {get; set; }
    TU SomeClassTU {get; set; }
}
```

I've created many interfaces which uses different `T` and `TU`.

```
public interface IFirstT: InterfaceT {}
public interface IFirstTU: InterfaceTU {}
public interface IFirstGlobal : IBaseInterface<IFirstT, IFirstTU> {}
```

I want to use `IFirstGlobal` on a new base interface without sending `InterfaceT` and `InterfaceTU` types (actually hide them).
Basically it means that IBaseInterface can get any `InterfaceT` & `InterfaceTU`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
public interface INew<T>
  where T: IBaseInterface<InterfaceT,InterfaceTU> 
{
  T SomeClass { get; set; } 
}
```

I expect that `T` would **accept** `IFirstGlobal` as a type - but it **won't**.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: inheritance relationships between types do *not* (often) apply to generic types *parameterized* by those types. An `IBaseInterface<IFirstT, IFirstTU>` does *not* inherit from `IBaseInterface<InterfaceT, InterfaceU>`. They're two unrelated types with no inheritance relationship.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so how can I avoid InterfaceT,InterfaceTU from bubbling up in my code ?

Comment: @ohadinho - do you want to be able to use the properties `SomeClassT` or `SomeClassTU` in the "higher" level code with the *exact* types? If so, there is probably no way around it. If not, maybe what you really want is a non-generic `interface IBaseInterface { InterfaceT SomeClassT {get; set; } InterfaceTU SomeClassTU {get; set; } }`?

Comment: You can't really. Perhaps generics isn't actually a match for your actual problem space.

Comment: Also, *maybe* covariance could be of help? Let's say you have `interface IBaseInterfaceOut<out T, out TU> where T : InterfaceT where TU : InterfaceTU { T GetT(); TU GetTU(); }` and your other `IBaseInterface` inherits from that and the implementing classes all just return the property values in the respective `Get` methods. Then you could have `interface IFirstGlobalOut : IBaseInterfaceOut<IFirstT, IFirstTU> { }` and `IFirstGlobal : IFirstGlobalBase, IBaseInterface<IFirstT, IFirstTU> { }`.

Comment: Then you could have `interface INew<T> where T : IBaseInterfaceOut<InterfaceT, InterfaceTU>` and implement it like `public class ActualNew : INew<IFirstGlobalOut>` -- you wouldn't have direct access to the properties and wouldn't be able to `set` them, but you'd still be able to read-access them via the `Get` methods. --- see also [out (generic modifier)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)